# Why I am getting this output? ( jQuery .append() issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### Why append is behaving quite differently here..can anybody explain this!

Recently while practicing jQuery got stuck here, Didn't understand what was happening: On the first button click the elements are getting appended normally as expected but on/after second click things(Output) are starting to get weird. Can someone please explain what is happening here...
I am new to jQuery.

```js
function appendText() {
  var txt1 = "<p id='set'>Text1</p>";
  console.log("Text1", txt1);

  var txt2 = $("<p></p>").text("Text2");
  console.log("Text2", txt2);

  var txt3 = document.createElement("p");
  txt3.innerHTML = "Text3";
  console.log("Text3", txt3);

  var txt4 = $("#set").html("Text4");
  console.log("Text4", txt4);

  $("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Append Test Example</p>
<button onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Multiple elements cannot share the same ID (in your case, `set`).

Comment: The logic does check out (although it's rather complex to explain). What are you wanting to happen here?

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```js
var ourButton = document.getElementById("btn");
    
var ourList = document.getElementById("our-list");

ourButton.addEventListener("click",func2);

newAddedText = 1;

function func2() {
  ourList.innerHTML += "<li>anything " + newAddedText + "</li>";
  newAddedText++;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Add New</button>
<ul id="our-list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document. Use [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. Also it is not good practice to mix JavaScript and jQuery unnecessarily.

When append second time, `('#set')` actually find first matched element which is already appended by the first button click and changes the html of it. Instead of referencing the element by *class*, you have to use the variable which contains the element.

Change

```
var txt4 = $('#set').html("Text4");
```

To

```
var txt4 = $(txt1).html("Text4");
```

```js
function appendText() {
  var txt1 = "<p class='set'>Text1</p>";

  var txt2 = $("<p></p>").text("Text2");
  var txt3 = document.createElement("p");
  txt3.innerHTML = "Text3";

  var txt4 = $(txt1).html("Text4");

  $("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Append Test Example</p>
<button onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve added a counter to your example which makes it easier to see what’s going on here. The number in brackets on each output line represents the button click which created that line.

```js
let counter = 0;

function appendText() {
  counter++;

  let txt1 = `<p id="set">Text1 (${counter})</p>`;
  console.log('Text1', counter, txt1);

  let txt2 = $('<p></p>').text(`Text2 (${counter})`);
  console.log('Text2', counter, txt2);

  let txt3 = document.createElement('p');
  txt3.innerHTML = `Text3 (${counter})`;
  console.log('Text3', counter, txt3);

  let txt4 = $('#set').html(`Text4 (${counter})`);
  console.log('Text4', counter, txt4);

  $('body').append(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Append Test Example</p>
<button onclick="appendText()">Append text</button>
```

#### Click 1:

```html
<p id="set">Text1 (1)</p>
<p>Text2 (1)</p>
<p>Text3 (1)</p>
```

But there’s no `Text4`! Refer back to the expression used to create `txt4`:

```js
$('#set').html(`Text4 (${counter})`)
```

This isn’t creating a *new* element, it’s fetching an *existing* element from the document. It *would* match `Text1 (1)`, but that element hasn’t been written to the document yet.

#### Click 2:

```html
<p>Text2 (1)</p>
<p>Text3 (1)</p>

<p id="set">Text1 (2)</p>
<p>Text2 (2)</p>
<p>Text3 (2)</p>
<p id="set">Text4 (2)</p>
```

Now `Text1 (1)` exists, so the `txt4` selector can retrieve it.

Since `txt4` is created by fetching the existing `#set` element, the first element with `id` equal to `set` is used: `<p id="set">Text1 (1)</p>`. At this point, some potentially unexpected jQuery behaviour comes into play: when appending an element which already exists in the document, [it’s removed from its original location first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17100961/1813169).

#### Click 3:

```html
<p>Text2 (1)</p>
<p>Text3 (1)</p>

<p>Text2 (2)</p>
<p>Text3 (2)</p>
<p id="set">Text4 (2)</p>

<p id="set">Text1 (3)</p>
<p>Text2 (3)</p>
<p>Text3 (3)</p>
<p id="set">Text4 (3)</p>
```

Just before this click, we have an **`id` conflict** (see the previous snippet). Recall that the [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) should be unique (emphasis mine):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which **must be unique** in the whole document.

Since your document is no longer valid HTML, we enter the world of *undefined behaviour*. JS calls to lookup an element by its `id` attribute may return any element with that `id`. In my browser (and potentially many others), the first is returned.

Just as it happened in click 2, an element with the `id` `set` is removed from the document to be used as the new `txt4`. In this case, that was the first one: `<p id="set">Text1 (2)</p>`.

#### Click n:

From this point on, the pattern repeats. Every click removes the first element with the `id` `set`, but adds two more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're mixing different things. The first 3 txt variables are just ok, you create HTML elements in different ways to append them to your HTML document. But let's take a look at this line;

```
var txt4 = $("#set").html("Text4");
```

Here is the problem. You're selecting the element whose id is `set`, which is `txt1` and you are changing it's inner HTML to just 'Text 4' and then appending the result of that operation (which is none) to your HTML.

If you remove that line, everything works ok, but with that line, here is what it's happening:

**Step One**

You click append text and, because there wasn't any elements already added, the following is appended:

```
<p id="set">Text1</p> <--- txt1
<p>Text2</p>          <--- txt2
<p>Text3</p>          <--- txt3
```

As `txt4` returns nothing, nothin else is added

**Step Two**

You click again the button and:

```
----------- previous step --------------
<p id="set">Text1</p> <--- txt1
<p>Text2</p>          <--- txt2
<p>Text3</p>          <--- txt3
----------- current step ---------------
<p id="set">Text1</p> <--- txt1
<p>Text2</p>          <--- txt2
<p>Text3</p>          <--- txt3
```

You espect that to happen, but because you had your `txt4` variable changing the `<p id='set'>` elements, here is what really happens:

```
----------- previous step --------------
<p id="set">Text4</p> <--- txt1 BUT changed by txt4
<p>Text2</p>          <--- txt2
<p>Text3</p>          <--- txt3
----------- current step ---------------
<p id="set">Text1</p> <--- txt1
<p>Text2</p>          <--- txt2
<p>Text3</p>          <--- txt3
```

The new Text1 `<p>` remains unchanged because when you select it in `txt4`, it isn't yet present.

If you change nothing in your code but the last line:

```
From this
$("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4);

To this
$("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3);
```

Yoy will reproduce exactly what I've written here. If you append also `txt4` the `<p>` elements gets "shuffle". I suspect that is because txt4 contains `jQuery`, because the [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) as setter, returns that.